# How to achieve this main content next to the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I am working on a school project I want to do a responsive text which is similar to the picture below and further when it switch to mobile view the text have to change its position and fit below the hero image.

how to change the size according to the screen size?

I am a beginner trying to learn things on my own.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');

* {
    font-family: Raleway;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

.brand-title {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: .5rem;
}

.navbar-links {
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: .75rem;
    right: 1rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.img-hover-zoom {
  height: 500px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
.img-hover-zoom img {
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}
.img-hover-zoom:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.hero-text {
    grid-area:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 55%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }
  h1 { 
    text-align: left; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    font-family: Agency FB, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 2em;
}
p {
    font-size: 3vh;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .toggle-button {
        display: flex;
    }

    .navbar-links {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li a {
        padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }

    .navbar-links.active {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <title>Responsive website</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reset-css@3.0.0/reset.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Assets/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <header>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="brand-title">Brand Name</div>
            <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="navbar-links">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="img-hover-zoom">
            <img src="/img/hero.jpg" alt="This zooms-in really well and smooth" width="500px" height="500px">
          </div>
          <div class="hero-text">
            <h1>Travel around the World</h1>
            <br><br>
            <p>Traveling is a very crucial part of life as it is the best way to get out of the busy schedule. 
            It is also to experience life in different ways.Traveling is actually a good remedy for stress, anxiety 
            and depression. It also improves the mental and physical health. We only have one life and 
            we should thank it for making us more advanced creature on this planet. Not only do we get to 
            experience the beauty of nature, different geographies ,topographies, and people. 
             </p>
          </div>
     </header>
          <script src="/Assets/main.js" defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

on my website

[image]

Comment: grid is great for switching stuff around like that.  Maybe consider building your page's layout in grid using "grid areas".  You can then set the grid areas in media queries.

Comment: How can I do that ? I am sorry I am new to this

Comment: Since this is a school project, I'll respectfully say "Look it up".  There are lots of tutorials online about how to use grid and `grid-area`.  Give it a try and if you have a specific problem you've tried to solve but can't, post a new question.

Comment: If I am getting you correctly you need to use media queries to achieve it.  See https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp.  See about bootstrap grid https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp. Learn by yourself...